# my program keeps looping and I don't know why

Tags: python, loops

the user is required to input package weight and after I input the packages it gives me the correct answer but the answer keeps on repeating.

heres the code:

```
more = "y"

count = 0

total = 0
x = 0


while(more == "y"):
    lbs = eval(input("Please enter the weight of the package: "))

    if (lbs >= 1 and lbs <= 2):
        op1:(lbs * 1.10)
        x = op1
        count += 1
        total += x
        print("The current package shipping cost is:",op1)

    if (lbs > 2 and lbs <= 6):
        op2 = (lbs * 2.20)
        x = op2
        count += 1
        total += x
        print("The current package shipping cost is:",op2)

    if (lbs > 6 and lbs <= 10):
        op3 =(lbs * 3.70)
        x = op3
        count += 1
        total += x
        print("The current package shipping cost is:",op3)


    if (lbs > 10):
        op4 =(lbs * 3.80)
        x = op4
        count += 1
        total += x
        print("The current package shipping cost is:",op4)

    if (lbs == 0):
        print("your package cannot be delivered")

    more = input ("Do you want to enter another Package? <y/n>: ")
while(more == "n"):
    print("Your total shipping cost is:",total,"for",count,"packages")
```

Comment: Well, what were you expecting `while(more == "n"):` to do?  Since there's nothing inside that loop that changes `more`, how could this ever end?

Comment: `more` will always be `y`, so it will keep running. And why `eval()`? Use `int()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line -

```
while(more == "n"):
     print("Your total shipping cost is:",total,"for",count,"packages")
```

You do not need the while loop. Just do -

```
print("Your total shipping cost is:",total,"for",count,"packages")
```

Additionally, you do not need `eval()`, just use `int()` -

```
lbs = int(input("Please enter the weight of the package: "))
```

You could use `range()` function instead of the >= <= ... etc. things. For e.g. -

```
if lbs in range(1,2+1): # Not really useful, still you could use this
    # code
```

It is not significant, so to keep it simple, you do not need to use the `range` function

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just start with

```
while True:
```

and place a `break` after each `if` evaluation, then you get only correct input, and in case of incorrect input the while loop starts again with the input question.
The input question also requires the information that the weight needs to be in lbs.

Comment: No, you can also start with `more == 'y'`, too, but the value of `more` should change to `n` after if evaluation

Comment: sure this is the same, but more == 'y' is unnessesary information that decreases readability, since it is anyway not important. if the more is important later one can still use break and change y before it.

Comment: This is not about readability, it is about infinite loops in OP's code right?

Answer (score 0):

Since you deleted your previous question about your code is giving you errors and functions are not working...here I will explain what are your errors and the new program.

1.Your first error is you used def greeting function and you didn't complete the function and you have to define what the function should do when you call the function. You used `def Greeting():` but you didn't complete it,if you are using a `def` function you always have to complete it after():

2.Your 2nd error is your while loop is not correct.It has some logical errors

3.Your 3rd error is your functions(op1.op2,op3,op4) are in the wrong format that's why your program didn't work as you expect

here i update your previous question which was asked on 22nd October 2021...please go through this code and compare it to your one and learn your errors.

Good Luck buddy and always learn from your errors:)

new code:

```
def Greeting():
    print('good morning')
Greeting()
n=str(input("please input full name: "))
print("hello",n,"this program will allow you to input package weight and display price")


package_count=0 
total=0  
more=False
while more==False:
    more = input ("Do you want to enter another Package? <y/n>: ")
    if(more == "y"):
        lbs = int(input("Please enter the weight of the package: "))
    else:
        print('your total shipping cost is:',total,"for",package_count,'packages')
        break
if (lbs>=1 and lbs<=2):
        op1=(lbs*1.10)
        print('The current package shipping cost is: ',op1)
        package_count=package_count+1
        total=op1

elif(lbs>2 and lbs<=6):
    op2 = (lbs * 2.20)
    print('The current package shipping cost is:',op2)
    package_count=package_count+1
    total=total+op2

elif(lbs > 6 and lbs <= 10):
    op3 =(lbs * 3.70)
    print("The current package shipping cost is:",op3)
    package_count=package_count+1
    total=total+op3

elif(lbs>10):
    op4=(lbs*3.80)
    print("The current package shipping cost is:",op4)
    package_count=package_count+1
    total=total+op4


else:
    print("your package cannot be delivered")
more=False
```